# Differentiate a gaussian process

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes

Let $(X_t)_{t\in [0,1]}$ a centered Gaussian process. Assume the covariance function $K$ to be $\mathcal{C}^2$. Show that for all $t\in [0,1]$, $$\tilde{X}_t=\lim _{h\to 0}\frac{X_{t+h}-X_t}{h}$$ exists in $L^2$. Compute the associated covariance function.

We have $E((X_t-X_s)^2)=K(t,t)+K(s,s)-2K(s,t)$. In particular $t\to X_t$ (from $[0,1]$ to $L^2$) is continuous.

For all $s, t$ and $h$, we have 
\begin{align}
E(X_s\frac{X_{t+h}-X_t}{h})&=\frac{1}{h}(E(X_sX_{t+h})-E(X_sX_t))\\
&=\frac{1}{h}(K(s,t+h)-K(s,t))\\
&\to \frac{\partial K}{\partial t}(s,t) \text{ when $h\to 0$}.
\end{align}

If we can exchange the order of limit and expectation we obtain $$ E(X_s\tilde{X_t})=\frac{\partial K}{\partial t}(s,t) $$ and with similar computations $$E(\tilde{X_s}\tilde{X_t})=\frac{\partial ^2 K}{\partial t\partial s}(s,t) . $$ This corresponds to the covariance function. He remains me to show that $\tilde{X_t}$ exists in $L^2$ and justify the exchange of order of limit and expectation (probably by using the dominated convergence theorem). Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: $X_{t+h} - X_t$ varies like $h^{1/2}$.  Are you sure there shouldn't be a square in the numerator in the definition of $\tilde{X}$, or a power of a half in the denominator?

Comment: Why  do you think that $X_{t+h} - X_t\sim  h^{1/2}$ ?

Comment: For Brownian Motion, that increment is a normal with variance $h$. So most of the time it's within several deviations of $h^{1/2}$.

Comment: But it can be a Brownian Motion since $K(s,t)=min (s,t)$ is not a $C^2$ function.

Comment: Instead of being able to answer your question I'll instead ask you a question :) I see that I have no intuitive feel for why the above is true - I think it's time I learn more about autocovariance functions.  What course of study/book did this problem show up in? I like how it is phrased.

Comment: I just started learning about Brownian Motion and stochastics processes a week ago. This exercice is extract from a french book (J-F Le Gall, Mouvement brownien, martingales et calcul stochastique) that introduces these notions. It's the first exercice of the first chapter about Gaussian processes.